# MySQL query to SQLite query for activities for the past 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a query in MySQL that i want to convert in SQLite. This is my Query:

```
SELECT * FROM timelogs where `time` >= now() - INTERVAL 1 day
```

I'd like to get the time entries for the past 24 hours. Anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM timelogs
WHERE time >= datetime('now', '-1 day')
```

`datetime('now')` will return the current date time in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format, and then we can offset this by one day.